# How to configure callbackhandler for custom realm in Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish-3

I configured new custom realm for Glassfish v3 and deployed it. No errors founded on logs where Glassfish start.

Now I want to test my realm with simple dynamic web project but I don't remember how to configure callbackhandler to get login/password for users ? I believed that there was tag balise on web.xml or glassfish-web.xml to configure it but I can't find it.

Please help me to set up callbackhandler in my case :)

Olivier

Comment: in application-client.xml there is <callback-handler> tag but it seems to be nor present in web.xml or glassfish-web.xml...How to choose custom callback handler ? I don't want BASIC or FORM. Thanks